# DB2 cast decimal as string with dashes, then cast as date

Tags: php, mysql, database, db2

I'm trying to take the column 'extd2d' from a db2 table, which holds date values but it's a packed/decimal column.

So for 2018-02-02 it returns `20180202`

I'm trying to select it to match a mysql column that is a DATE data type which returns 2018-02-02. I'm thinking what I need to do in order to match them is cast the extd2d field as a string with the dashes, then cast that as a date.

I'm currently doing this:

```
select date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2))  as start_date,
from table1;
```

Which displays it in the correct YYYY-MM-DD format, but if I use the same line

```
date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2))
```

in a where clause to match it with the DATE column coming from mysql, it says it can't compare the two. Should I be casting this differently? Would it be better to go this way or to remove the dashes from the mysql date and compare?

EDIT:

This is how I've been comparing in a where clause:

```
 AND date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2)) >= {$row['start_date']}
```

Script :

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        sku_id,
        dealer_id,
        locations,
        s.sku_group_id as groupID,
        s.frame as frame,
        s.cover1 as cover,
        s.color1 as color,
        start_date - interval 7 day as start_date
    from placements p
    inner join skus s on p.sku_id = s.id
    where curdate() between p.start_date and p.expire_date
    group by sku_id, dealer_id
    limit 100";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

    {
        $resultData[] = $row;

$sql2 = "
    SELECT
          framec,
          covr1c,
          colr1c,
          date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2))  as start_date,
          sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
      from table1
        where cstnoc = {$row['dealer_id']}
        AND framec = {$row['frame']}
          AND colr1c = {$row['color']}
          AND covr1c =  {$row['cover']}
          AND date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2)) >= {$row['start_date']}
    group by framec,covr1c,colr1c,extd2d
";

$result2 = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $sql2);

while($row2 = odbc_fetch_array($result2)){

        $db2Result[] = $row2;
}
}

print_r($resultData);
print_r($db2Result);
```

Comment: How are you comparing a value from DB2 and MySQL in the same `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that before. I updated with it now. Basically I'm pulling the 'start_date' value from mysql and it's a DATE data type

Comment: @GordonLinoff the other $row values from the mysql query are comparing fine, but it's not letting me compare the date values this way at all

Comment: . . Where are you doing the comparison.  The question should be tagged with that application.  Or, you should show the full (or simplified) query, showing how you are bringing together data from two different databases.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I've updated with the script portion

Comment: @gordonlinoff hopefully that's more clear to what you're talking about. I updated the tag too

Comment: how many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: I only asked once before and deleted it to post this newer version. I guess until I get an answer or some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, though DB2 has a native date format, PHP doesn't, really. So when you pull a date from MySQL in PHP, you are getting a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, then comparing that to a `DB2 date` field. It would be better if you didn't cast at all, and remove the dashes from the MySQL field:

```
$sql2 = "
    SELECT
          framec,
          covr1c,
          colr1c,
          date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2))  as start_date,
          sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
      from table1
        where cstnoc = {$row['dealer_id']}
        AND framec = {$row['frame']}
          AND colr1c = {$row['color']}
          AND covr1c = {$row['cover']}
          AND extd2d >= " . str_replace('-', '', $row['start_date']) . "
    group by framec,covr1c,colr1c,extd2d
";
```

The real problem is that this is subject to SQL injection, so instead of concatenating values into your SQL, you should instead use parameter markers like this:

```
$sql2 = "
    SELECT
          framec,
          covr1c,
          colr1c,
          date(substr(extd2d,1,4)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,5,2)||'-'||substr(EXTD2d,7,2))  as start_date,
          sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
      from table1
        where cstnoc = ?
        AND framec = ?
          AND colr1c = ?
          AND covr1c = ?
          AND extd2d >= ?
      group by framec,covr1c,colr1c,extd2d
";
$parms = array(
    $row['dealer_id'], 
    $row['frame'], 
    $row['color'],
    $row['color'],
    intval(str_replace('-', '', $row['start_date']))
);
$prep_stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $stmt2);
$success   = odbc_execute($prep_stmt, $parms);
```

The parameter markers `?` and replacement data in the array protect you from injection because the SQL parser will not treat the replacement data as part of the SQL statement. As you can see, it is not terribly difficult to protect your program from malicious users, so you should do that every time you use SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer, I think that makes sense. So if I remove the dashes like that will I get an accurate comparison? i.e. if my start_date value is 2018-02-02 and it becomes 20180202, will the DB2 date compare accurately for days and months?

Comment: Also, I just tried this but if I do it as is, with Double quotes, it fails and says the '{' for my row value is unexpected. If I change that line to use single quotes then it says the use of '-' is not valid

Comment: Take out the `{` and `}`. The DB2 date is not a date, but a packed number that represents a date. It know nothing about years months and days. But if you make sure it is formatted as YYYYMMDD, then it will handle the comparison correctly. The problem is when those numeric dates are formatted as MMDDYYYY or DDMMYYYY that you start to run into problems when you compare with anything other than `=`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now, and yes they are formatted YYYYMMDD for sure. Thanks, I got it working now!